# Stop execution of sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a huge SQL script with many batches (using `GO`).

On certain conditions, I want to stop the whole execution of this script.

I tried using `NOEXEC`, but I keep on getting invalid object errors, since my script includes creating and adding data to new tables and columns.

I do not want to use `RAISERROR`, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I don't know of a way of doing this. Are the GO statements necessary? I'd look to either make it a single batch and break out of that or find some way of executing these batches individualls (e.g. Powershell or other scripting language, SSIS, put them into stored procedures etc).

Comment: How are you executing this script?  Management Studio?  SQLCMD?  Application?

Comment: I am executing it in management studio

Answer (score 4):

There are no good solutions to this problem. One way you can share data between batches is tables(persistent or temporary). So you can have some logic that depends on some state of that table or value of particular columns in that table like this:

```
--CREATE TABLE debug(col int)
--INSERT INTO debug VALUES(1)
--DELETE FROM debug


SELECT 1
GO

SELECT 2

SELECT 3

GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM debug)
    SELECT 6

GO
```

Just add `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM debug)` this line to every place in script that you want to skip and depending on the fact that the table has some rows or not those code blocks will execute or not.

Comment: Seems like a good solution,  but it won't make sense in my situation since I have a huge script and its not advisable to add check before every batch.

Comment: @RandomUser, you just have no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

just use  SET NOEXEC ON  when you want to stop execution.

```
 Go
 Select 'I want to kill the job after some error or based on some validation.
 Go
 Select 'Raiserror not working'
  Go
 Select 'I have to be admin to define severity 20'
 go
Select 'I got an error, come custom validation failed, I don't want to run the 
 rest  of the script'.
Go
 SET NOEXEC ON
 Select 'rest of the script should not run after NOEXEC on executed'.
```